# activar zend debugger en PHP5.6

Tags: php, zend

estoy utilizanodo XAMPP5.6 para programar con PHP y quiero activar el "zend debugger", para ello estoy siguiendo [esta guia](http://scripts.sil.org/cms/scripts/page.php?site_id=ductile&item_id=ZendDebuggerWXampp) pero **no consigo que me aparezca en el listado de phpinfo()**¿Alguien lo ha conseguido y me puede explicar que estoy haciendo mal?

Esto es lo que añadi a mi php.ini:

```
[Zend Debugger] 
zend_extension_ts = "C:\xampp\apache\bin\ZendDebugger.dll" 
zend_debugger.allow_hosts = 127.0.0.1 
zend_debugger.expose_remotely=always
```

Gracias, saludos:D

Comment: En esa misma guía dice que no uses `zend_extension_ts =`

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta @Mariano, supongo que te refieres a :"Do NOT use **zend_extension** = ..."